# One User can access a method at a time in jsf+java+jsp in dynamic web project

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I have one method which  will create a file and transfer it to other machine in java.
It is a dynamic web project , java , jsp and jsf has been used for the same.

The problem is The application can be accessed by different users at a time, But for every user I am using one method which changes something in a file a transfer it to different machine .The problem is if at a time some other user logged in and changes the file then the previous user will get the wrong file.

I want to put that method as synchronized so that at a time only one user can access the same method .

Please suggest me to handle concurrent user in dynamic web project in java .
I am using JSF

Comment: Can you post some code please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all take in account that each user request is handled by the server on a separate thread so you are in a multi-thread environment even if you do not create threads in your code.

If possible I would create a different instance of the object, able to manage the file, for each user/request. In this way you will be sure that different users will not overwrite/change settings.